# Interfacing ADS1115 with FPGA

Tags: fpga, adc, interface

I'm trying to interface an [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115-q1.pdf) to a [MAX10 FPGA](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/details/fpga/max/10.html).

I've managed to start reading from the ADS1115, but I'm facing another problem as of now. Even when I connect A0 to 3.3 V I'm reading junk i.e. constantly fluctuating values from as low as 500 to 63000 from the conversion register.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use a logic analyzer to verify the timing of your HDL with that of the datasheet, always do this even if you think you have it working

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. See p22 of the datasheet, and Figure 37. Be aware though that if you are not writing to the register in the first place, it is probable that you have an error in your I2C interface and so also won't be able to read back either.

Table 8 shows all registers are fully read/write.

Comment: I need to read 16 bits of config register not hi, lo thresh Register.

Comment: See Table 8 of the datasheet - all registers are read/write.

Comment: Due to some reason, I am not able to read continuous conversion from it.I am getting a constant value of 255 from the I2C read. Is there any particular way I need to configure this board in my program? It would be very appreciable if you could also suggest a probable alternative to this ADC-I2C board which is pre-configured or at the very least isn't as complex as this.

Comment: P.S I have already configured the config register to my needs. Any help on what order of passage i need to pass the bytes will be very helpful.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific in terms of what you are asking, as there are many things that can cause issues when using these interfaces. For example, are you using an I2C IP block, or did you make your own? This is about as simple as it gets for I2C, and I don't know your application so can't recommend any other ADCs.

Comment: the application im  using is involves pairing a mq135 gas sensor with this adc

Comment: also the i2c that im using is a IP

Comment: hey thanks for all the help earlier... ive managed to start reading from the ads1115... but im facing another problem as of now... even when i connect a0 to 3.3v im reading junk i.e constantly fluctuating values from as low as 500 t0 63000 from the conversion register... any help would be much appreciated...